# setState to allow change to appear on interface immediately for flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, settings, setstate

I am working to update my username in firebase and i would like the change to appear immediately on the interface. How do i set the state for this? This is the code i've written so far for my 'update' button. Thanks!

```
RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async { //change username

                  FirebaseUser user = await Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUser();
                  UserUpdateInfo updateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
                  updateInfo.displayName = _newUsernameController.text;
                  user.updateProfile(updateInfo);
                  print('USERNAME IS: ${user.displayName}');

                  setState(() {
                    //user.displayName = _newUsernameController;
                  });
                    Navigator.pop(context);

                    },
                  color: Colors.indigo,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 20, right: 20),
                  child: Text("Save", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign `user.displayName` to a variable within `setState` and display that variable.

```dart
String username = 'Old Name';

...

child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
        Text(username), // HERE!
        RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async { //change username

                  FirebaseUser user = await Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUser();
                  UserUpdateInfo updateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
                  updateInfo.displayName = _newUsernameController.text;
                  user.updateProfile(updateInfo);
                  print('USERNAME IS: ${user.displayName}');

                  setState(() {
                    username = user.displayName;
                  });
                    // Navigator.pop(context); why???

                    },
                  color: Colors.indigo,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 20, right: 20),
                  child: Text("Save", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
    ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in need of accessing data from multiple widgets/views, you should consider searching for a state management solution.

Have a look at [this documentation page](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt) from Flutter Docs, it is great for understanding the fundamentals of state management.

Also `user.updateProfile(updateInfo)` is an [asynchronous task](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await). You might want to await it before taking further actions like navigating back.